# Parsing JSON double brackets with Java

Tags: java, json, api, parsing, weather-api

I'm having some trouble as I've hit a roadblock in learning how to parse JSON with json simple.

To make myself concise;

I am trying to parse this bit of JSON from a url

```
"hourly": {

"summary": "Clear throughout the day.",

"icon": "clear-day",

"data": [

{

"time": 1550379600,

"summary": "Clear",

"icon": "clear-day",

"precipIntensity": 0,

"precipProbability": 0,

"temperature": 20.18,

"apparentTemperature": 14.31,

"dewPoint": 13.79,

"humidity": 0.76,

"pressure": 1024.47,

"windSpeed": 4.08,

"windGust": 5.25,

"windBearing": 30,

"cloudCover": 0.07,

"uvIndex": 0,

"visibility": 10,

"ozone": 342.67

}
```

so, in using json simple, this is how I am parsing this JSON

```
try{

String genreJson = IOUtils.toString(new URL(url));

JSONObject genreJsonObject = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parseWithException(genreJson);

//get the title

System.out.println(genreJsonObject.get("hourly")); //THIS WORKS

//System.out.println(genreJsonObject.get("visibility"));

//get the data

JSONArray genreArray = (JSONArray) genreJsonObject.get(0);

//get the first genre

//JSONObject firstGenre = (JSONObject) genreArray.get(0);

//System.out.println(firstGenre.get("data"));

}

catch (IOException | ParseException e){

e.printStackTrace();

}
```

So, in calling `System.out.println(genreJsonObject.get("hourly"));` I get everything within the brackets titled "hourly". My intent is to parse for the data within the "hourly" bracket, although I can't figure out how to parse for a title within a titled bracket. Specifically, I need the time, the precipProbability, precipIntensity, and precipProbability (this attribute is not in the example).

I apologize for any lack of detail as I'm doing this as part my first hackathon, and I'm trying not to fall asleep right now.

I greatly appreciate anyone's help.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if you create  a Java POJO and map the Json to the Java class (using Jackson for example) and then call the corresponding methods on the Java class?

Comment: I'll look into that and give it a shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is object to describe your json "data" part:

```
class Data {
  private Long time;
  private String summary;
  private String icon;
  private Double dewPoint;
  // add all the fields you need

  // add empty constructor + getters and setters
}
```

if you want to skip some of the fields in "data" which you don't care about use

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Data{ 
   ...
}
```

Your parent object is "hourly", so:

```
class Hourly {
  private String summary;
  private String icon;
  private List<Data> data;

  // add all the fields you need

  // add empty constructor + getters and setters
}
```

At this point the Java POJO classes describe the Json data, so you're ready to map the JSON to the Java classes.

To read this with Jackson, you will need the String representation of the Json (without any URL parts), so let's assume you can do that in a string called "inputJsonString".

Reading this with Jackson will be as simple as:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Hourly hourly = mapper.readValue(inputJsonString, Hourly.class);
```